# Rails generator: print all code in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've typed this

```
rails g scaffold supplier user:references company_title:string address:string description:string
```

now it generate the controller

```
class SuppliersController < InheritedResources::Base
end
```

but I would like to have all of the code for each actions because its more likely that I have to edit every time. How could I tell to "rails generator" to print all code on that file?

Comment: As Graeme stated, you are using Inherited Resources.  If you aren't taking advantage of the superclass, probably don't need to include it in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `inherited_resources` gem, so the normal REST actions are not provided in each controller.  Instead they inherit from `InheritedResources::Base`.

If your application requires you to override the controller actions each time maybe it would be easier not to use `inherited_resources`.  Controllers will inherit instead from `ApplicationController` and scaffold should generate the REST actions.

Alternatively, to keep `inherited_resources` but force the generators to generate the REST actions, add to your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.app_generators.scaffold_controller = :scaffold_controller
```